# C# ASP.NET MVC : System.AggregateException: Some services are not able to be constructed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have been working on a project for a while, and I have been stuck on this error for a while:

> System.AggregateException: 'Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: BookShoppingCartMvcUI.Repositories.ICartRepository Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: BookShoppingCartMvcUI.Repositories.CartRepository': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]' while attempting to activate 'BookShoppingCartMvcUI.Repositories.CartRepository'.)'
>
> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]' while attempting to activate 'BookShoppingCartMvcUI.Repositories.CartRepository'.

Here are some parts of my code:

`Startup.cs`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'DefaultConnection' not found.");

    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseNpgsql(connectionString));

    services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options =>
        options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false)
        .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();
    services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

    services.AddScoped<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
    services.AddScoped<ICartRepository, CartRepository>();

    services.AddControllersWithViews();
}
```

`ApplicationDbContext`:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql("DefaultConnection");
        }
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        var admin = new IdentityRole("admin");
        admin.NormalizedName = "admin";

        var client = new IdentityRole("client");
        client.NormalizedName = "client";

        builder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasData(admin, client);
    }

    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ShoppingCart> ShoppingCarts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CartDetail> CartDetails { get; set; }
    public DbSet<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

`CartRepository`:

```
public class CartRepository : ICartRepository
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;
    private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;

    public CartRepository(ApplicationDbContext db,
        UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
    {
        _db = db;
        _userManager = userManager;
    }
}
```

`ICartRepository`:

```
public interface ICartRepository
{
    Task<int> AddItem(int productId, int qty);
    Task<int> RemoveItem(int productId);
    Task<ShoppingCart> GetUserCart();
    Task<int> GetCartItemCount(string userId = "");
    Task<ShoppingCart> GetCart(string userId);
    Task<bool> DoCheckout();
}
```

I have been looking for a solution, I had found threads with similar problem, but I have not been able to fix the issue myself.

Answer (score 0):

You have only registered the service `UserManager<ApplicationUser>` but are trying to resolve `UserManager<IdentityUser>` in your `CartRepository`. Therefore the DI container does not know about `UserManager<IdentityUser>` and cannot construct a service which needs an instance of `UserManager<IdentityUser>` to be created.

You should register `UserManager<IdentityUser>` or use a generic registration to correct this issue.